# Split and display Child ID from Parent ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with ID as "parentID" to the parent div and based on this, I am dynamically adding "ChildID" to all its child divs along with its "parentID".

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.split-id', function() {
  var parentID = jQuery('.parent').attr('id');
  var childID = jQuery('.child').attr('id', jQuery(this).closest('.parent').attr('id') + 'ChildID');

  jQuery('#displayParentID').html('Parent ID : ' + parentID);
  jQuery('#displayParentChildID').html('Parent Child ID : ' + childID);
  jQuery('#displayOnlyChildID').html('Child ID only : ' + childID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" id="parentID">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div id="displayParentID"></div>
<div id="displayParentChildID"></div>
<div id="displayOnlyChildID"></div>

<a href="javascript:;" class="split-id">Split</a>
```

How can I get all child element IDs without parent div IDs? like below onClicking of `Split` tag...

Parent ID : parentID
Parent Child ID : parentIDChildID
Child ID only : **ChildID** (*This is what I am expecting*)

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/sqk1cjtb/31/)

Comment: It's not clear what you're attempting to achieve here, and the syntax you've used is incorrect for a couple of reasons. You also appear to be giving the same `id` to multiple elements. Can you explain a little more about why you need to do this, as I'm sure there's a more effective way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do

Comment: Is this what you want `http://jsfiddle.net/94vakty0/` But note that in the process you duplicate ID, and that is a no no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what exactly is purpose of what you are asking, but you can replace your js code in your fiddle with this and it works as you expected. 
* Mind that, when you use attr function to set a property it is returning Object, not only string label.
* If you will give multiple children the same id it will not work, because in html code ids need to be unique

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.split-id', function () { 

  var parentID = jQuery('.parent').attr('id');
  var childElement = jQuery('.child').attr('id', parentID + 'ChildID');
  var childID = childElement.attr('id');
  jQuery('#displayParentID').html('Parent ID : ' + parentID);
  jQuery('#displayParentChildID').html('Parent Child ID : ' + childID);
  jQuery('#displayOnlyChildID').html('Child ID only : ' + childID.replace(parentID, ''));  

});
```

If you have some more questions, go on and ask.